# Prestashop 1.6 : Changing order status to payment didn't generate an invoice

Tags: php, pdo, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem in a client Prestashop 1.6.1.6 shop, when we are changing the order status to payment accepted or remote payment accepted, there's no generated PDF Invoice.
This is only for orders paid by module bankwire or cheque. For other payment methods, the PDF invoice is generated normally.
I have debugged many function in Order class method setInvoice and many others, and i found the problem in method setInvoiceDetails

```
protected function setInvoiceDetails($order_invoice)
{
    if (!$order_invoice || !is_object($order_invoice)) {
        return;
    }

    $address = new Address((int)$this->{Configuration::get('PS_TAX_ADDRESS_TYPE')});
    $carrier = new Carrier((int)$this->id_carrier);
    $tax_calculator = $carrier->getTaxCalculator($address);
    $order_invoice->total_discount_tax_excl = $this->total_discounts_tax_excl;
    $order_invoice->total_discount_tax_incl = $this->total_discounts_tax_incl;
    $order_invoice->total_paid_tax_excl = $this->total_paid_tax_excl;
    $order_invoice->total_paid_tax_incl = $this->total_paid_tax_incl;
    $order_invoice->total_products = $this->total_products;
    $order_invoice->total_products_wt = $this->total_products_wt;
    $order_invoice->total_shipping_tax_excl = $this->total_shipping_tax_excl;
    $order_invoice->total_shipping_tax_incl = $this->total_shipping_tax_incl;
    $order_invoice->shipping_tax_computation_method = $tax_calculator->computation_method;
    $order_invoice->total_wrapping_tax_excl = $this->total_wrapping_tax_excl;
    $order_invoice->total_wrapping_tax_incl = $this->total_wrapping_tax_incl;
    $order_invoice->save();
    var_dump($order_invoice);exit;
}
```

The $order_invoice object is not empty and returning data but when saving with

```
$order_invoice->save();
```

the method save is returning false,
It's strange to me, is it a problem with database saving, the database has reached its limit?
Normally the after the save, the object get an id, form the ObjectModel herited class.
Any help will be appreicated thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the order state(s) configuration?

Comment: Yes they exists with default customization

Answer (score 0):

It was database structure problem related to the order_invoice table, i fixed the problem by adding the missing fields, i think it was an update issue.
Prestashop one click ugrade module is causing many problems, hope it will stable in nexte releases.

Comment: Hi tarek, I have the same problem but in my case there seem to be all the needed fields. What are the fields the were missing in your case? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Claudio, i forget the fields you can check with a new prestashop install table

Comment: Thank you, I finally found out that my problem is different. I'm working with MySQL 5.7 and a query issued by prestashop throws an error. If you're interested, I reported the bug here: http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCSX-8607.

Thank you anyway :)